# Same response with different access token(different user) with Google api php client

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client

I have created an web app which fetched users drive information and show it on a browser. It is working fine for single user but when I try this app with different account it still shows same result for both the user.
I checked the logs and there are different access token different user. When I am fetching the result from http get call using those access token I get different result.
I think some issue is there with the Google api php client.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in 2.0 Beta version google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC

Version "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta" is worked correct.